# how to save/get current state of an object to/from the context path of a Servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, contextpath

I'm new to Java Servlets, and for the application I'm currently working on, (some kind of Proxy without forwading or Redirect classes) I would like to save an object to the context path of the application.

I know there are similar questions, but I can't get it to work or I just don't understand it.

Do I have to specifiy the context path in the web.xml?
Do I Need a context listener?

This is the code snippet but the Objects within the saved Object are null;
how can I save the current state of an Object to the context path?

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {

        if(this.getServletContext().getAttribute("oldConnector")==null){
            Connector connection = new Connector(); 
            connection.sendRequest(request);
            this.getServletContext().setAttribute("oldConnector", connection);
        }else{
             ((Connector)this.getServletContext().getAttribute("oldConnector")).sendResponse(response); 
             this.getServletContext().removeAttribute("oldConnector");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The response object of HttpServletResponse is never null**, because it is created by the web container when a first request is made to your servlet.

Therefore, the attribute "oldConnector" is not set, so you are getting its value as null.

**Suggestion:** Set the context attribute "oldConnector" by removing the if(response==null) condition. And retrieve that attribute in another servlet or same then remove it if required to.

Below code may help you for your query in comments.

```
        if(getServletContext().getAttribute("oldConnector") == null){
            getServletContext().setAttribute("oldConnector", "old value");//dummy value added, replace it with your connection object.
            System.out.println("oldConnector attribute has be set.");
        }else{
            getServletContext().removeAttribute("oldConnector");
            System.out.println("oldConnector attribute has be removed");
        }
```

Comment: So the way i save and retreave the Object "connection" is correct ?

Comment: Actually it's not the way. It's the if condition than will never be true, since response object is never null in your case. remove the if else condition, set the connection object in context attribute and later on in other/same servlet retrieve that connection object.

Comment: I know what you mean i only want to know if this.getServletContext().setAttribute("oldConnector", connection) is correct. Also, is there a way to determine whether request/response is empty ?

Comment: yes, it's correct to set the connection object in the application context as you did. the if condition can be used to determine that the request/response is empty. I guess, you think removing the connection object from context will set the response as null. But this is not true. Just try to set response=null, but this is not recommended.because the response is not yet completed.

Comment: Okay, I'm now doing a little work around and try 
 to get the servlet context Attribute even if it hasn't been
 set yet at the start of the get method, so i can ask if it's null. If thats the case it's an incoming request. Within the if Statement I save the connection Object to the context path so when the Response arrives the getServletContext will not be null and i know that it's an incoming Response after I resent the Response i will then remove the Object connection and set it again after the next incoming request.

Comment: try this if(this.getServletContext().getAttribute("oldConnector") != null){}. Instead of if(response==null) {}

Comment: thats what I ment and i tried if(this.getServletContext().getAttribute("oldConnector")==null)  for checking if it's a request but so far it's not working

Comment: please update your code in the snapshot query. I need to see what you have written.

Comment: i thought that an incoming Response would trigger the doGet method as well but at least when using urlconnection this is not the case so i dont Need to check whether a request or Response is triggering the doGet

Comment: The doGet is triggered when specify the method="get" or nothing(default method is GET) in your request Form.